# Changing the height of JvectorMap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jvectormap

I am having a problem setting up the height of the JVectorMap in the css. I have looked at the documentation at http://jvectormap.com/. I also looked at

```js
    $('#world-map').vectorMap({
      map: 'world_mill',
               initial: {
           fill: 'white',
        stroke: '#9d2b2b',
        "fill-opacity": 1,
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        r: 5,
       backgroundColor: 'white',
               
      },
    });
```

```css
    maps{
      height: 900px;
        width:100% !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jvectormap/2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row centered">
        <div class="col-lg-12 maps">
       <div class="maps" id="world-map" >
    
               
             
              </div></div></div></div>
```

different suggested solutions which none of them seems to be working. My code is below and I want to figure out a way of changing the height of the map.